salesforce - Trying to extract all the OLI records of a Account and display those on front-end
Have used the below codes. Getting the data as I want in js but it is not getting displayed on the front-end. Could someone help figure out what am I doing wrong?
html:
<template>

    <lightning-card title="Grand Child Component">

        <template if:true={mapofAccountIdVsOLIs}>

<template for:each={mapofAccountIdVsOLIs} for:item="mapkey" for:index="index">

                <tr key={mapkey.AccountId}>

                    <th scope="col">{mapkey.AccountId}</th>

                    <th scope="col">

                        <template for:each={mapkey.OLIs} for:item="mapval" for:index="index1">

                        <div key={mapval.Id}>{mapval.Id}</div>

                        </template>

                    </th>

                </tr>

            </template>

</template>

    </lightning-card>   

</template>

js file:
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';

import getChildRecords from '@salesforce/apex/grandChild.getGrandChild';

import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class GrandChild extends LightningElement {

    mapofAccountIdVsOLIs=[];

    connectedCallback(){

        this.loadGrandChildRecords();

    }

    loadGrandChildRecords(){

        getChildRecords()

            .then(result=>{

                console.log('=====================>',JSON.stringify(result));

                for(var key in result){

                    this.mapofAccountIdVsOLIs.push({AccountId : key, OLIs: result[key]});

                }

                console.log('=====================>',JSON.stringify(this.mapofAccountIdVsOLIs));

            })

            .catch(error =>{

                this.showToast('Error', 'An error occurred while fetching the records. '+ error.body.message, 'error');

            });

    }

    showToast(title, message, variant){

        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({

            title: title,

            message: message,

            variant: variant,

        });

        this.dispatchEvent(evt);

    }

}


Apex class:
public class grandChild {

    @AuraEnabled

    public static Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>>  getGrandChild() {

        Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>> resultMap = new Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>> ();

        Map<Id,Account> mapOfAccount= new Map<Id,Account>();

        Map<Id,Opportunity> mapOfOpp = new Map<Id,Opportunity>();

        for(Account aa: [select Id, Name, (select id, Name from Opportunities) from Account limit 1]){

            mapOfAccount.put(aa.Id, aa);

        }

        for(Opportunity aa:  [Select id, (select id, Name, UnitPrice from OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where AccountId in :mapOfAccount.keySet()]){

            mapOfOpp.put(aa.Id, aa);

        }

        for(Id aa : mapOfAccount.keySet()){

            if(mapOfAccount.get(aa).Opportunities != null){

                for(Opportunity bb : mapOfAccount.get(aa).Opportunities){

                    if(mapOfOpp.get(bb.Id).OpportunityLineItems != null){

                        if(resultMap.containsKey(aa)){

                            resultMap.get(aa).addAll(mapOfOpp.get(bb.Id).OpportunityLineItems);

                        }

                        else{

                            resultMap.put(aa, mapOfOpp.get(bb.Id).OpportunityLineItems);

                        }

                    }

                }

            }   

        }

        return resultMap;

    }

}

Getting the data as I want in js but it is not getting displayed on the front-end. Could someone help figure out what am I doing wrong?
